# Transação em Postgress no NodeJs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, query, funções, transações

Estou querendo encapsular minha execução de SQL no banco de Postgress.
Meu desejo inicial é chamar um método para executar uma query em específico e outro método para executar uma transações de várias queries.

```
exports.executaSQL = function (select, listaParametros){
    client.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        client.query(select, listaParametros, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return result.rows;
            client.end(function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
    });
};

/**
var objetoListaSelect = [];
objetoListaSelect.push({
    select : 'SELECT 1 WHERE ID=$1 AND ID=$2'
    params : [1, 6]
});
objetoListaSelect.push({
    select : 'SELECT 1 WHERE ID=$1 AND ID=$2'
    params : [1, 6]
});
**/
exports.executaTransacao = function (objetoListaSelect){

};
```

Gostaria que a segunda function **executaTransacao** tivesse a execução na ordem em que foi adicionada ao array, lembrando a execução assíncrona das queries, qual seria uma boa solução?

Agradecido desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar Promises para fazer isso. Criando uma função de ajuda para fazer cada pedido encapsulado numa Promise

```
function queryPromise(obj) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        client.query(obj.select, obj.params, function(err, result) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(result.rows);
        });
    });
}
```

depois podes usar `Promise.all()` para esperar por todos os pedisos.

Seria assim:

```
var objetoListaSelect = [];
objetoListaSelect.push({
    select : 'SELECT 1 WHERE ID=$1 AND ID=$2'
    params : [1, 6]
});
objetoListaSelect.push({
    select : 'SELECT 1 WHERE ID=$1 AND ID=$2'
    params : [1, 6]
});

exports.executaTransacao = function(objetoListaSelect) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        client.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            Promise.all(objetoListaSelect.map(queryPromise)).then(function(results) {
                client.end(function(err) {
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    else resolve(results);
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

E quando chamares essa função recebes uma promise. E para leres os resultados seria algo como:

```
const executaTransacao = require('./oTeuFicheiro').executaTransacao;

executaTransacao().then(function(resultados){
    console.log(resultados);
}).catch(function(erro){
    console.log(erro);
});
```

Comment: Olá Sergio, ainda não testei por completo, mas gostaria de comentar que precisei acrescentar o new para criação da Promisse: `exports.executaTransacao = function(objetoListaSelect) {
    return _new_ Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        client.connect(function(err) {`

Comment: @ErickJPeiker exato, na pressa esqueci o `new`, mas é isso mesmo. Diz-me depois se funcionou. Eu uso muito este tipo de encapsulamento com MySQL em Node.